# If to put a dummy condition in sql query like between 'mindate' and 'maxdate', would efficiency of query be reduced?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008,

```
select * from OneTable
```

compare to

```
select * from OneTable where OneTable.SomeDate between 'MINDATE' and 'MAXDATE'
```

which one is fast or they are same fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those queries are only functionally equivalent if you're retrieving the entire table in which case providing an extra clause which in no way limits the data being retrieved is unlikely to be any faster. It *may* be slower <sup>(a)</sup> by virtue of the fact that you access the data via an index. With the full table scan option, you don't ever need to touch the index.

It will certainly be faster to limit the rows retrieved at the server side rather than get everything and then filter at the client side (assuming of course that you have an index on your `SomeDate` column).

But that's only for the case where you're not retrieving every row.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Or your DBMS may figure out early that you've asked for everything and do a full table scan anyway, minimising the impact.

But it will probably *still* be marginally slower just because this check needs to be done up front.

Comment: I know the second query won't be faster. I'm just wondering if it'll be slower. I was hoping SQL server would do optimization to remove the dummy condition I added?

Answer (score 0):

In that simple case this probably doesn't matter. However when you have a more restrictive where clause this could cause a full table scan even though not needed and decrease your performance considerably.

Comment: Oh, no.. this is what I worried. I used 'mindate' and 'maxdate' as defaule value of a search in program. I hope this is not too bad for performance.

Comment: if you need a dummy so that you have a valid where clause try a 1=1 this should have less side effects.